# how to recuperate the list of the potlet created in liferay 6.2 using java

Tags: liferay-hook

My problem is to recuperate the list of the portlet created in liferay 6.2
 without display the default portlet in liferay 6.2.
i try this code 
<%
                            boolean includeSystemPortlets = false;

```
                        List<Portlet> portlets = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets(company.getCompanyId(), includeSystemPortlets, false);

portlets = ListUtil.sort(portlets, new PortletTitleComparator(application, locale));

                        for (Portlet curPortlet : portlets) {
                            if (Validator.isNull(curPortlet.getPortletId()) || hiddenPortletIds.contains(curPortlet.getPortletId())) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            editPermissionsURL.setParameter("portletResource", curPortlet.getPortletId());
                        %>
```

but it display all the portlet created and the default portlet

i want to change this code : "  List portlets = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets(company.getCompanyId(), includeSystemPortlets, false); " because it display all the portlet

Comment: please help my problem is to display only the portlet created without the default portlets of liferay

Comment: i resolve this problem by this code : <%
       boolean includeSystemPortlets = false;

       List<Portlet> portlets = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets(company.getCompanyId(), includeSystemPortlets, true); 

       List<Portlet> portletsToShow = new ArrayList<Portlet>();
       for (Portlet curPortlet : portlets) {
        if(curPortlet.getRootPortletId().contains("_WAR_nmshtaportlet")) {
         portletsToShow.add(curPortlet);
        }
       }
       portlets = portletsToShow;